# regex matching curly braces in java inside very large html file

Tags: java, regex

From the following String I want to match charaters between `{  }`

I tested `{"chkin.*"}` but in code it is not working

```
    String re = "\\{\"chkin.*}";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(re);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(document.html());
```

> document =
>    {"chkin":"2018/1/18","chkout":"2018/1/19","adults":"2","children":"1","childAge":"2","brandId":"2199","packageType":null,"countryId":0,"isVip":false,"swpToggleOn":null,"cacheId":null,"tla":"NGO","stayLength":null,"daysInFuture":null,"ticketedTravelers":null,"evalMODExp":true,"partnerName":"","partnerPrice":"0.0","partnerCurrency":"","partnerTimestamp":"0"},"taapPackageRateEnabled":false,"loyaltyData":{"rewardsAmount":0,"formattedRewardsAmount":null,"rewardsDollarValue":null,"redemptionFloorAmount":0,"expediaPlusBranded":"Expedia+","expediaPointsBranded":"Expedia+
>   points","awardType":"points","hasLoyaltyEarnings":true,"hasGPSLoyaltyEarnings":false,"tier":null,"swpToggleDefaultState":true,"canUserBurn":false,"displaySwpToggle":null},"displayQualifyingNights":false,"showExcludeTaxMessage":true,"showNoRefundIcon":false,"drrMessageForGPSEnabled":false,"omnitureData":

This document is a very large `html` file I am showing only part of it.

**Fixed** :

Problem was at document.html() part of code. Actually document was a huge `html` file that I have shown just a part. So `Intellij Idea` was complaining that `very large String constant inside matcher`. So I divided large `html` file into chunks and then regex suggested by @Bohemian worked perfectly fine. Thanks

Comment: Not my downvote, but you should be using a JSON parser here.

Comment: I read that as an abbreviation for chicken.

Comment: What is your regex matching now, and what do you want it to match? ie what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `.*` is greedy

Comment: Additionally "it doesn't work is not a valid program description".

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is *greedy*; it will match everything up to the last `}` it can find.

Try this:

```
String re = "\\{\"chkin.*?\\}";
```

Adding the `?` makes it *reluctant*, which matches as *little* as possible.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1
\\{\"chkin.*?}
 ^

Comment: @Avi try the edited version

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536)
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:496)

Comment: @Avi I can't reproduce your error, this regex compiles fine https://ideone.com/xmx3r7 (even without escaped `}` since it is not special unless it closes unescaped `{`). Post your *real* code.

Comment: I think your regex is fine may be some problem with `document.html() ` part of my code.

Comment: As I mentioned before problem was at `document.html()` part of code. Actually `document` was a huge `html` file that I have shown just a part. So `Intellij Idea` was complaining that `very large String constant inside matcher`. So I divided large `html` file into chunks and then above `regex` suggested by @Bohemian worked perfectly fine. Thanks.